# What usually causes "import error: no module named..."?

Tags: python, installation

I encountered an error in installation in python-quaec. 
It is: `ImportError: No module named 'singletons'`

I am using mac and python3.4

However, obviously the singletons.py file is in the same folder of `_init_.py`

What usually causes import error like this?

Ref: http://www.cgranade.com/python-quaec/#installation